# After changing list.php => error: the resource is not defined

Tags: error, log, resources

after chaning line 87 in list.php (/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product) from:

> $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

to

> $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()->joinField('inventory_in_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id','is_in_stock>=0', 'left')->setOrder('inventory_in_stock','desc');

I am doing this so that products that are in stock are shown before products out of stock.

It's working, but when I search in the search bar, see attached image for error.
[image: Error log]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by removing my search module "searchanise". So it works like a charm now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use this : https://github.com/MaximusDecimus/ShowInStockFirst

Free module and will do the job - tested it and it is working

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thank you for your answer.

I tested the plugin on my webshop, but it did not work. I have contacted the author of the module but with no response yet.

Comment: why it didn't work, what issue did you get? do you have another module effecting the category listing or creating custom sorting?

Comment: Hi again, I do not believe that I have any other module affecting category listing or sorting. I made sure that the module was enabled on my admin page, and it showed up, but it didn't re-arrange the products on my website.